# Sending Apache HTTP Server's custom logs to Syslog on Windows server

Tags: logs, windows-server

I want to send Apache HTTP Servercustom logs to a syslog server; built in is the functionality to this with the error logs but not custom logs. Can someone recommend a tool for this job, running on a Windows server?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but you might want to have a look at this article:  [Sending Apache httpd Logs to Syslog](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/10/12/httpd-syslog.html):

> Unfortunately, only the error log has this feature built in. It's
>   extremely useful to also have your access logs logged to a remote
>   server, for the reasons described earlier.
>
> There is a technique to allow you to log your access log to syslog as
>   well. However, as with any other article of this nature, I encourage
>   you to check the Apache web server documentation site because this
>   feature may be built-in at some point in the future, rendering this
>   technique obsolete. At the moment, here's what you need to do. This is
>   a two-step process.
>
> First, create a script that is capable of sending entries to syslog:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/perl
> use Sys::Syslog qw( :DEFAULT setlogsock );
>
> setlogsock('unix');
> openlog('apache', 'cons', 'pid', 'local2');
>
> while ($log = <STDIN>) {
>             syslog('notice', $log);
> }
> closelog This script, written in Perl, uses the [Sys::Syslog module][1] to send data to a syslog server. Make sure that you have the
> ```
>
> Sys::Syslog module installed, but it should be standard on any fairly
>   recent version of Perl.
>
> Put this script somewhere and make it executable. For this example, I
>   assume that you've put the script at
>   /usr/local/apache/bin/apache_syslog.
>
> Second, point your access log at this script using the piped logfile
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> CustomLog |/usr/local/apache/bin/apache_syslog combined
> ```
>
> The apache_syslog script will launch when your web server starts up,
>   and it processes logfile entries as it receives them from the server.
>   The while loop will continue for the lifetime of the Apache server
>   process.
>
> As you can see in the script, it sends these entries to a syslog
>   facility named local2, so configure your syslog server with an entry
>   in /etc/syslog.conf like:
>
> ```
> local2.*    @192.168.200.12
> ```
>
> See the documentation for Sys::Syslog for more information on the
>   options that are available to you in this module.
>
> With this configuration, in the event that your server is compromised
>   or there is catastrophic drive failure, you'll still have a remote
>   copy of your logfiles to find out what happened.
>
> Also note that if you have multiple CustomLog directives, you can have
>   multiple logfiles. So, if you want to have a local logfile in addition
>   to a remote one, just add an extra CustomLog directive pointing to a
>   local logfile:
>
> ```
> CustomLog /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log combined
> ```